# Orthogonal irreducible decomposition of $\otimes^2 E$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

Recall that $$ \otimes^2 E = \wedge^2 E \oplus S^2_0E\oplus {\bf R}$$

Clearly this is an $O(n)$-decomposition. Irreducibility can be checked from the following property:

Let $Ae_1=e_k,\ Ae_2=e_l,\ Ae_k=e_1,\ Ae_l=e_1,\ Ae_i=e_i\ (i\neq 1,\ 2,\ k,\ l)$ Then $$
 A(e_1\otimes e_2 + e_2\otimes e_1)= e_k\otimes e_l+ e_l\otimes e_k$$

But some book [Gallot-Hulin-LaFontaine, *Riemannian Geometry* (1987), p.150] introduces classical invariant theory so that there exists following notations $$ \sum t_{ij}t^{ij},\ \sum t_{ij}t^{ji},\ ({\rm trace}\ (t))^2 $$

So they concluded that there exist **at most three irreducible components**. And note that this argument is used to decompose Riemannian curvature tensor.

How can we prove that?

Comment: Can you state the reference??Maybe a bit of context would help.

Comment: 155 page in the book Riemannian geometry - Gallot, Hulin, Lafontaine